# Rich datatable performance issues

Tags: performance, jsf, datatable, richfaces

Wondering if anyone has come across performance issues with rich datatables when they are displaying large data sets. Sorting a table of around 150 rows takes about 12 seconds to load.

I'm looking into adding a loading image. Has anyone implemented something to 'manually' sort the dataset and reload the table?

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Wou can add `a4j:status` with modal panel or image which will be displayed until sorting

Comment: Looks like this is a known performance issue...adding loading images for now